# Como adicionar uma classe em uma <li> ao clicar sobre ela, deixando somente ela com essa classe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Por exemplo:

1. Tenho mais de uma `ul` com suas `li`;
2. Se clico em uma `li` da primeira `ul` ela tem que adicionar uma classe;
3. Se clico em uma `li` da segunda `ul`, ela adiciona essa mesma classe. Só
   que não interfere na lista da primeira `ul`;

Pra ficar mais esclarecido, é como se cada `ul` fosse um grupo de radio button, onde apenas um por grupo é marcado.

Alguma idéia?

Comment: Interessante. São 3 respostas satisfatórias, mas escritas de maneiras relativamente distintas. Fiquei curioso com o seguinte: que parâmetros poderiam ser usados para definir qual é a melhor?

Comment: Realmente todas respostas deram certo. Não sei ainda em qual votar.

Comment: Faz um [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) e vota na que tiver melhor desempenho, afinal provavelmente será o melhor algorítimo.

Comment: Como funciona @GabrielGartz ? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Fiz os testes pra você Jefferson, espero que ajude: http://jsperf.com/alteradores-de-classe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui tem o link para o exemplo completo:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Mu2F/

Basicamente o seguinte código faz é:

1) Quando o documento estiver carregado adiciona evento click ao cada li.

2) Quando é clicado, remove de todas os li do ul mais proximo a classe selected

3) Adiciona classe selected para o li que foi selectionado

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 porque teve o [melhor desempenho](http://jsperf.com/alteradores-de-classe) entre as opções fornecidas.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você deve remover a classe de qualquer `li` dentro da `ul`:

```
$('#id_ul li').removeClass('minha_classe');
```

Depois você adiciona na `li` que foi clicada o evento:

```
$(this).addClass('minha_classe');
```

isso deve ser feito dentro de um `click` na `li`.

**Exemplo completo**

```
$("#id_ul li").on("click", function(){
    $('#id_ul li').removeClass('minha_classe');
    $(this).addClass('minha_classe');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `.siblings()` assim vicê só vai alterar os elementos que estiverem dentro do mesmo nível da **ul**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

É um código curto e cumpre exatamente sua necessidade.

É basicamente o mesmo código do [Serhiy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5011/serhiy) só trocando o uso o `.closest()` e `.find()` você usa apenas o `.siblings()` e manipula todos os elementos que estiverem no mesmo nível do selecionado.

Comment: Ummm, onde viu a parte de modificar todos os li? Só se modificam os li do ul mais proximo... É o que closest faz..

Comment: Realmente me equivoquei, já editei a resposta :D

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, dê uma classe a suas `ul`s. Vamos nomeá-las de `tipoRadio`. E a classe dos itens selecionados será `selecionado`.

```
$(function() {
    $(".tipoRadio").on("click", "li", function() {
        var ul = $(this).parent(".tipoRadio");
        ul.children("li").removeClass("selecionado");
        $(this).addClass("selecionado");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreLeria/TsH2S/)

Comment: Não ficaria melhor aplicar o evento `click` direto na `ul`?

Comment: Na `ul`? Porque?

Comment: Porque você adiciona um evento na filha da ul, pra pegar a ul. Ficaria melhor, na minha opinião, aplicar o evento só em `.tipoRadio` e atribuir apenas o $(this), que já te dá a `ul` direto, não?

Comment: Mas eu preciso da `li` clicada de qualquer jeito. Como eu vou saber qual selecionar?

Comment: Verdade, não tinha pensado nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar, e se quiseres obter mais conhecimento sobre este assunto, sugiro que acesse este site https://www.codeschool.com/courses, nele existem alguns cursos gratuitos que lhe serão muito úteis.